# How can I check the object count in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

My below code is crashing. I can see that `filteredOther` has `0` object. I think it is crashing due to this reason but I am really a newbie in `Xcode`.

How I can solve this problem?

```
NSString *UserID = @"";
UserID = [[filteredOther objectAtIndex:selectedIndex.row] objectForKey:@"id"];
```

Comment: Show the error message. This part `[filteredOther objectAtIndex:selectedIndex.row]` is causing the crash? We need more context then.

Comment: First you need to check whether "filteredOther" is nil / has zero value.

Comment: @MGP, no need to check for `nil` if OP has already initialized it before use.

Comment: then need to check the number of object in it..if index is beyond its count-1 then it will definitely crash...like ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException...

Comment: @MGP, right. That what I have answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `count` method of `NSArray`.
You can access it as a method, like `[array count]` 
or as a property: `array.count`.

```
if (filteredOther) {

     if ([filteredOther count] > selectedIndex.row]) {

          UserID = [[filteredOther objectAtIndex:selectedIndex.row] objectForKey:@"id"];
     } else {
         NSLog(@"Index out of bounds");
     }

} else {

     NSLog(@"Array is nil");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `filteredOther` count by calling `filteredOther.count`.

Not sure exactly what you want to achieve, but e.g.

```
if (filteredOther.count > selectedIndex.row) {
    UserID = [[filteredOther objectAtIndex:selectedIndex.row] objectForKey:@"id"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am assuming that, you have double check that, you're accessing an `NSArray` which having objects of `NSDictionary` kind.

When you're not sure about accessing an object in array's index. You can have a check like this:

```
if (filteredOther.count > selectedIndex.row) {
    //do good stuff.
} else {
    //need to check.
}
```